# Save and Update in a controller together in Yii

Tags: activerecord, model, yii, controller

There are two tables in my db, users and profile. Profile has user_id as a primary key. Every user can have only one profile. When I upload a image file its name is stored in profile table with that user_id. When there are other fields to be updated in profile table, I first check whether there is already a record with that user_id. In my Profile model I have written

```
public function checkForSaveOrUpdate()
{
    return self::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
}
```

and my controller file looks something like this

```
    public function actionCreateInfo()
      {
        $profile = new Profile;
        $profile->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

        if(isset($_POST['Profile']))
        {
            if($profile->checkForSaveOrUpdate() === null)
            {
                $profile->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];
                if($profile->save())
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Profile has been saved successfully');
            }
            elseif($profile = $profile->checkForSaveOrUpdate())
            {
                $profile->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];
                if($profile->update())
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Profile has been updated successfully');
            }

            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }

        $this->render('createInfo',array('profile'=>$profile));
}
```

My problem is when I already have a record in database,in profile, and I submit a new form the old data is all deleted and only the current values submitted are updated, whereas it should keep the old values and only update the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you instaciate the model like:

```
$model = new YourModel;
```

you will have the `$model->isNewRecord` set to `true`:

```
var_dump($model->isNewRecord); // true, in this case you use $model->save()
```

When you find a record, the same property will have the opposite value:

```
$model = YourModel::model()->findByPk(1);
var_dump($model->isNewRecord); // false - and now you use $model->update(), instead.
```

Comment: How can you do both? I mean initially you are asking me to make a new $model and then check by findByPk? That is the reason I have written a function in my Model class.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to static function

```
 public static function checkForSaveOrUpdate()
    {
        return self::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
    }
```

Then modify action as

```
public function actionCreateInfo()
{
        $profile = Profile::checkForSaveOrUpdate();
        if($profile===null)
        {
            $profile=new Profile;
            $profile->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
        }
        if(isset($_POST['Profile']))
        {
            $profile->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];
            if($profile->save())
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Profile has been saved successfully');
           $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }

        $this->render('createInfo',array('profile'=>$profile));
}
```

Comment: would you elaborate to exactly why you asking me to make it static?

Comment: here you first check (ie before render view) whether this record is there in profile.if that user is already there in profile, it first load the data then it render to view(createInfo).if there is no such user in profile table it will create one

Answer (score 0):

Your `POST` data probably includes all model attributes, including those left blank by the user set to the empty string; the empty string is an accepted value for massive assignment unless otherwise stated in the model rules; a massive assignment is what you actually do with `$profile->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];`.

One solution would be to unset those attributes that you don't want to update, e.g. those containing an empty string, in the controller.

But this kind of rule should be defined in the model and triggered by calling the `validate()` method, which you are now skipping by calling `update()`. You better call `save()` because internally calls `validate()` as opposed to `update()`.

A rule for a default value is defined like this:

```
array(
    'attr_name',
    'default',
    'setOnEmpty' => true,
    'value' => null
)
```